# Why does configure say no C compiler found when GCC is installed?

Tags: linux, gcc, terminal, sphinx, yum

I am trying to make [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) from source on a 32-bit CentOS 6 VPS.

When I run this command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx
```

I get this error output:

```
checking build environment
--------------------------

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no

checking for compiler programs
------------------------------

checking whether to compile debug version... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/gnotes/sphinx':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

What I don't understand is that GCC is installed so why can't configure find an acceptable C compiler?

Here's the output of yum:

```
sudo yum install gcc

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.metrocast.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
base                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.5 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Package gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What gives?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

if the installation is success then you will have a full set of development tools. Such as gcc, g++, make, ld ect. After that you can try the compilation of Code Blocks again.

Since `yum` is deprecated you can use `dnf` instead:

```
dnf groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Answer (score 17):

Install GCC in **Ubuntu  Debian Base**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: subtle difference here

Answer (score 7):

i have same problem at the moment. I just run `yum install gcc`

Comment: Yea you might not necessarily need everything that comes with Development Tools

Answer (score 6):

Try specifying `CC` while configuring:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx
```

Also check if your compiler produces executables.  The following should produce an `a.out`:

```
echo "int main(){0;}" | gcc -x c -
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe gcc is not in your path?  Try finding gcc using `which gcc` and add it to your path if it's not already there.

Comment: `which gcc` outputs `/usr/bin/gcc` and `echo $PATH` outputs `/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/gnotes/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/gnotes/bin`. How would I add it to the path?

Comment: How can I add to the .profile file? Is there a command for it?

Comment: [to-permanently-set-path-on-linux][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/1278112

Answer (score 1):

Sometime gcc had created as `/usr/bin/gcc32`. so please create a `ln -s /usr/bin/gcc32 /usr/bin/gcc` and then compile that `./configure`.

Comment: In that case I would suggest to instead do `CC=/usr/bin/gcc32 ./configure` instead, you should be careful when making symlinks in system directories like that since it might confuse your package manager if it would try to write to /usr/bin/gcc later.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with mind.
I tried  using sudo apt-get install build-essential
It still won't work.
I simply created a hardlink to the gcc-x binary in the /usr/bin/ folder.
sudo ls /usr/bin/gcc-x /usr/bin/gcc

That worked for me!

Comment: In that case I would suggest to instead do `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-x ./configure` instead, you should be careful when making symlinks in system directories like that since it might confuse your package manager if it would try to write to /usr/bin/gcc later.

Answer (score 0):

The below packages are also helps you,

```
yum install gcc glibc glibc-common gd gd-devel -y
```