# Sending an email in Python from an executable file

Tags: python, email, command-line

I've been sending emails from the command line of my Raspberry Pi with this

```
echo “Body text” | mail -s Subject targetperson@example.com
```

code.  How would I put this in an executable python file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work comment below if it doesn't I'll delete:

```
import os
os.system('echo “Body text” | mail -s Subject targetperson@example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a file called 'send_email'

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

address = sys.argv[1]
subject = sys.argv[2]
message = sys.argv[3]  # Probably want to do some escaping on this and subject

os.system('echo "%s" | mail -s "%s" %s' % (message, subject, address))
```

Put this file on your [PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux) and run the following to make it executable:

```
chmod +x send_email
```

Now you should be able to send an email as follows:

```
send_email foo@bar.com "Important Subject" "Here is a message"
```