# java 7 features not working on ubuntu with java version "1.7.0_51"

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-7, diamond-operator

According to `java -version` this is what my Ubuntu Java environment is like:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

My `javac -version` is:

```
   javac 1.6.0_30
```

How do I change my javac version? Thanks for the tip @SotiriosDelimanolis. ;) (If you are reading this and have the same problem read the comments. I link to a page that describes how to do this on ubuntu).

I am trying to run the following program:

```
 import java.util.*;

   class Separate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     String text = "<head>first program</head> <body>hello world</body>";
     Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>(); //1 Compiler error
     try(Scanner tokenizingScanner = new Scanner(text)) { //2 Compiler Error
      tokenizingScanner.useDelimeter("\\W");
      while(tokenizingScanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = tokenizingScanner.next();
            if(!word.trim().equals("")) {
                    words.add(word);
            }
      } //end while
     } //end try

            for(String word: words) {
                    System.out.print(word + " ");
            } //end for

    }
```

I receive these errors upon trying to compile:

```
 Separate.java:8: illegal start of type
 Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
                                 ^
 Separate.java:9: '{' expected
 try(Scanner tokenizingScanner = new Scanner(text)) { 
    ^
 Separate.java:9: ')' expected
 try(Scanner tokenizingScanner = new Scanner(text)) { 
            ^
 Separate.java:9: ';' expected
 try(Scanner tokenizingScanner = new Scanner(text)) { 
                                                  ^
 Separate.java:9: 'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'
 try(Scanner tokenizingScanner = new Scanner(text)) { 
 ^
  Separate.java:24: reached end of file while parsing
  }
  ^
  6 errors
```

These errors seem like they should not be errors. The first error is showing that the diamond notation found in Java 7 is not correct syntax or something when it is correct. This error is shown with 1 above in the comments.

The other errors stemming from the Scanner object creation in the try block is a try with resources that is also a Java 7 feature. This line is marked with 2 above in the source code.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Now do `javac -version`.

Comment: Also, it's `useDelimiter`.

Comment: are you running it from any IDE or just compiling directly with javac ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi compiling directly from a shell

Comment: I updated my question thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis :D Do you know how I can change which version of java runs when I use `javac`?

Comment: You'll have to change your path. Check your java installations.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/308663/set-default-java-version check out this- this looks like a great tutorial. I set JAVA_HOME with the $PATH variable but I think I can change versions of `javac` in Ubuntu with `update-alternatives` - yes this changed my javac -version to 7 ! :D

Comment: It works now that I updated javac with update-alternatives and then selected Java 7 :D Thanks for your expert help @SotiriosDelimanolis :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your code is not compiled under JDK 7. Check the version of your compiler (as Sotirios mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Check your PATH environment variable, seems like it is pointing to an older JDK.

You can check to see which javac is being used by using

```
which javac
```

You can directly call the new JDK by using it's full path
e.g.

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac
```

But if you want to call javac anywhere you will have to change the PATH environment variable to point to the newer JDK.

How you modify your PATH depends on your setup. You'll have to remove the older path from PATH that points to JDK1.6 and add in a new path that points to JDK1.7

Example:

If

```
which javac
```

produces

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30/bin/javac
```

Then your path might look something like this, notice the jdk1.6.0_30

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30/bin`

Change that to the proper path (jdk1.7.0_51)
`PATH=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin`

Useful links:

[Environment variables in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

[Setting a PATH value permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

Comment: awesome. I just used the `update-alternatives` command to choose which version of `javac` to run and it worked. :D  What you are posting here is very helpful though. I will have to look into modifying my $PATH variable. Thank-you for addressing this complex issue. Also I had forgotten about the `which` command. Great stuff here. Thanks @lex