# bash script unable to automate installing ruby with rbenv and ruby build

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, ruby-2.1

The shell script below runs without error but when it finishes , I discovered that it only ran the first part of the script that installs **rbenv** but doesn't call all the lines from **echo "========= Cloning ruby build ========="** till the end. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 the Lubuntu variant.

If I type each command in the script directly into the terminal everything works and ruby 2.1.2 is installed but if run the script instead, **ruby_build and ruby 2.1.2** are not installed though **rbenv** is.

Any suggestion how to resolve this.

rbenv_ruby_installer.sh

```
   rbenv_install.sh

   sudo apt-get -y  update && apt-get upgrade 

   echo "======================================="
   echo "========= Cloning Rbenv ========="
   echo "======================================="

   cd
   git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
   echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
   exec $SHELL

   echo "======================================="
   echo "========= Cloning ruby build ========="
   echo "======================================="

   git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
   echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
   exec $SHELL

   echo "======================================="
   echo "========= Installing Ruby with Rbenv ========="
   echo "======================================="
   rbenv install 2.1.2
   rbenv global 2.1.2
   rbenv rehash
   ruby -v
```

Comment: "exec $SHELL" is your problem.  That causes the shell to replace itself with no arguments, no script, nothing to do.  It exits.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so should I use **source ~/.bashrc**

Comment: No.  You should not be modifying ~/.bashrc and just append the directories to your current value for PATH:  PATH+=:/path/to/whereever

Comment: Ok thanks, but one last question. If the path is not added to ~/.bashrc, how do I ensure each time I exit the terminal and start a new terminal instance, this path is not lost? Something along that lines was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux

Comment: Yeah, you just don't want to append to .bashrc every time you run a script.  Typically, my bashrc has a loop looking for various directories and adds them to PATH (and MANPATH, etc.) as they are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use:

```
exec $SHELL
```

instead add logic to your ~/.bashrc to look for these directories.  In scripts that install (clone) hierarchies from somewhere, *they* may want new directories in their PATH, but do not auto-edit your ~/.bashrc file every time you run a script.  Add search logic a la:

```
for d in $HOME/.rbenv/bin $HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
do test -d $d && PATH+=:$d ; done
```