# Tesseract PHP wrapper failed to open file

Tags: php, tesseract

There is a Open source PHP wrapper class for **Tesseract** (https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php) but i'm having problems using it:

Installed it successfully with composer, but when I call

```
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR('img/c11a67cdd171790771fcf33ec78461d9.png');
$tesseract->setTempDir('/var/www/dir_name/imgRead/');
$tesseract->setWhitelist(range(0,9));
```

When I run `echo $tesseract->recognize();` I get

```
Message: file_get_contents(/var/www/dir_name/imgRead/573534798.txt): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The author says:

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure that the tesseract binary is on your $PATH

but i'm not sure what this means exactly, how can I check that the binary is on my $PATH? Anyone use this before?

Comment: what linux are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. check your environment variable if the binary for Tesseract is added in your path issue **printenv** command on your terminal, you should see something like

   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin"
2. if it does not exist, add something like in your ~/.profile

   export PATH=$PATH/usr/bin:/path/to/your/tesseract

or you can check out different ways on how to add one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your path via PHP using

```
$path = getenv('PATH');
putenv("PATH=$path:/usr/local/bin");
```

where */usr/local/bin* is the location where you **installed** Tesseract.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the self Problem. Is there somebody how have a solution?

My Path is:

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin
```

My Path to tesseract is:

```
tesseract: /usr/local/bin/tesseract
```

I use Cent OS 6 and the new PHP

Comment: I presume if you post this as a question, you are more likely to get an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the installation of Tesseract, on terminal check tesseract by

$ tesseract -v

make sure the output is close to this output. should have these libs, if its missing the libs then Tesseract is not writing txt file anywhere and that's why it can't find it.

this is my output on centos 6

tesseract 3.02.02
leptonica-1.73
libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.2.1) : libpng 1.2.49 : libtiff 3.9.4 : zlib 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Check if  TesseractOCR is installed in your system, if not:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Tesseract-ocr-php is simply doing an exec(cammande) on system installed TesseractOCR