# Cannot use commands 'postgres' or 'pg_ctl'

Tags: postgresql, installation

I am on Unix. I have got postgresql-9.3 installed.
When I want to start the server using `pg_ctl` or `postgres`, the terminal gives me:

```
The program 'postgres' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install postgres-xc
```

Can't I start the server without this postgres-xc?

Comment: the server can also be started using  /etc/init.d/postgresql start

Comment: What kind of "Unix" are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must be remnants of the `postgres-xc` package you had installed previously.

Since you just installed `postgresql-9.3` and don't seem to have any databases in use, yet, I suggest to *completely* purge all postgres packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.2
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-xc
...
```

Until there's nothing left:

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

Then start from scratch. Your instance of `pg_ctl` seems to belong to the package `postgres-xc`. This should be gone after you've uninstalled the package. Find out with [one of these commands](https://wiki.debian.org/WhereIsIt#A.22I_have_a_file_.27quux.27_on_my_system.2C_which_package_does_it_belong_to.3F.22):

```
dpkg -S pg_ctl
dlocate pg_ctl
apt-file search pg_ctl
```

`pg_ctlcluster` is provided by the package `postgresql-common`.
`pg_ctl` is provided by the package `postgresql-9.3`.

[More about starting Postgres in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/server-start.html)

Comment: on a rather confused Server your command dpkg -l | grep postgres helps plenty to see what Ubuntu thinks it has installed. +1

Answer (score 2):

Due to reasons a normal install of postgres will not place the **postgres** binary file in the path.

Adding the right directory to the path solves the problem (temporarily).

```
PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin:$PATH
```

To make it permanent on my Ubuntu machine I added the line to **/etc/environment** this makes it work for all users.

The correct way to set the PATH is different for different systems, for more info see see:

[How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you might be missing a few things.

Try:
`sudo apt-get install postgresql-client` and
`sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`

The message about installing xc is a dud, it's probably suggesting that based on what it scanned inside the xc repositories.

Here's a good reference to this problem and its solution: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72580/missing-the-pg-ctl-package-in-postgres-9-3-installation

Answer (score 0):

You must install *postgresql-client*:

`sudo install postgresql-client`

Try to enter this command to the console:

`sudo -u postgres psql`