# How to add $PATH after shell execution exit

Tags: shell

I want to install some tools in specific directory in `install.sh`and call them in `test.sh`, so I add the path like this:

```
# part of install.sh
path_add()
{
    if [ -d "$1" ] && [ ":$PATH:" != *":$1:"* ]; then
        echo "add $1 to PATH"
        export PATH="$PATH:$1"
        echo $PATH
    else
        echo "$1 already existing in PATH"
    fi
}
```

the `echo` shows that the `$1` has been added to `$PATH`, but when `install.sh` exit, the `$PATH` do not contain the specified path just added, how to add it permanently and can affect the continuing shell environment?

Comment: This post may help you:

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux"

Answer (score 0):

```
# part of install.sh
path_add()
{
    if [ -d "$1" ] && [ ":$PATH:" != *":$1:"* ]; then
        echo "add $1 to PATH"

        #export PATH="$PATH:$1"
        # global
        echo "export PATH=$PATH:$1" >> /etc/profile
        # or local
        # echo "export PATH=$PATH:$1" >> ~/.profile

        echo $PATH
    else
        echo "$1 already existing in PATH"
    fi
}
```

**/etc/profile** - global system setting

**~/.profile** - per user settings