# Vagrant Berkshelf could not find the 'berks' executable in your PATH. When running 'vagrant up'

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, chefdk

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'district' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Vagrant Berkshelf could not find the 'berks' executable in your PATH.

Please download and install the latest version of the ChefDK from:

    https://downloads.getchef.com/chef-dk

and follow the installation instructions. Do not forget to add the ChefDK to
your PATH.
```

- I downloaded the latest version of ChefDK as instructed.
- How would I add the path to Berkshelf in the vagrant file?

Here is the my current Vgrantfile:

```
$ cat Vagrantfile
# vi: set ft=ruby :

    Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
      config.vm.define 'district' do |app|
        app.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'

        app.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
          v.memory = 1024
          v.name = 'district'
        end

        app.ssh.forward_agent = true
        app.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4567, host: 4567

        app.vm.synced_folder './', '/home/vagrant/WhatsMyDistrict'

        app.berkshelf.enabled = true

        app.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
          chef.log_level = :debug
          chef.custom_config_path = 'chef_solo.config'
          chef.run_list = ['whatsmydistrict::default']
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: show us your `Vagrantfile`

Comment: @BMW

Editing the post to contain the `Vagrantfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've added `/opt/chefdk/bin` to your `$PATH`.

It's recommended to have it prior to any ruby path locations - prepending is the easiest way to ensure this.

```
export PATH=/opt/chefdk/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I'n sorry, Im a real noob, could you elaborate a little more on how add something to a `$PATH?`
I'm sorry, I really want to learn this what could I read to become more familiar with these things?

Do I just run that command?

Comment: Yes, to add additional directories to your PATH, use the `export PATH=` command above. To permanently add to your PATH, check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux). For more information on the PATH variable, have a read through [this](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

Comment: Using the `export PATH=` command worked, I just had to replace the `/opt/chefdk/bin` part with the location **chefdk** was stored in my system.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users ChefDK is installed in `C:\opscode\chefdk\bin` as explained [here](https://blog.chef.io/the-chefdk-on-windows-survival-guide).

So you have to write this command line instead :
`export PATH=/c/opscode/chefdk/bin:$PATH`.

You can also follow these [steps](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) adding the path `C:\opscode\chefdk\bin`. You may have to restart your computer to apply the changes.