# How to Permanently update PATH variable in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to update path variable in UNIX

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

`PATH` variable includes the path, but next time I reboot the system it got flushed how can I update `PATH` variable permanently. So that I need not to update it every time I reboot the system.

Comment: Place it in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for all users, place this in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`
If just for a given user, place it in his/her `~/.bashrc`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: PATH variable initialization is preferable in the profile file, not the bashrc file.