# NPM not Working

Tags: node.js, debian, npm

```
$ sudo apt-get install python g++ make
$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
$ tar xvfvz node-latest.tar.gz
$ cd node-v0.10.21 (replace a version with your own)
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

I keep getting:

```
#nodejs --version   
/usr/bin/nodejs: No such file or directory
```

I understand though, 
everything seems to be installed here:

```
installing /usr/local/bin/node
```

How do i fix this?

Many thanks! I am very new to linux and how this all works.

By the way: `apt-get install nodejs` 
does work but it does not install version 0.12.

In addition, if i try npm it also cant find it.

Comment: If you're looking to manage versions of node, try out `n` or `nvm`

Comment: -bash: nvm: command not found
-bash: n: command not found

Comment: you could have google them at least =) https://github.com/creationix/nvm and https://www.npmjs.com/package/n (you probably want `nvm`, because `n` relies on node already working)

Comment: Not sure how this would fix the path issue on my nodejs install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `PATH` and thus the executable cannot be found. Add it to your `PATH` as described in [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux).

If you just link the one executable, you will have the same problem with any other executable added to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I will mark your answer correct if you can further explain why its a better fix to add to my path instead of -s.

Answer (score 1):

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/sbin/node

Just had to fix paths.

Comment: A better fix would be to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

> npm -v is not working in your system just do this

> open my computer or this pc

- right click & select properties
- click on advanced system settings
  in advanced tab click on environment variables
- in system variable remove semicolon from  ComSpec

  `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;`
- change this as

  `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

---

Now it will work..