# PATH dissapear when restart terminal

Tags: path, terminal, laravel-5

I am on linux, and I add the laravel command to my PATH by doing this: `export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"`   then I can run things like: `laravel new project`  to create a new a laravel project.

My problem is when I restart the terminal, and I cannot use it any more, until I re-add the laravel PATH.

Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export` only lasts for the duration of your terminal session. To have it automatically run each time you open a terminal, you'll need to add it to your `~/.profile` file (creating it if necessary).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/988423) for other details and solutions.

Comment: If I've answered your question, it'd be kind of you to mark it as Accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to my answer. Thanks!