# bash: ruby: command not found -- Other solutions only temporarily fix

Tags: ruby, bash, version

I'm running kubuntu (kde) on a chromebook and have ruby installed, along with rails. Everytime I close an instance of the konsole, reopen it, and try to check ruby's version

```
ruby -v
```

I get the error

```
bash: ruby: command not found
```

However, I'm able to get the version of rails

I've been able to tempoirarly fix this by typing

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
exec $SHELL -l
```

but when I close out of konsole again, I get the same error upon reopening.

Comment: A better duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux - sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding those lines to your `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`. `.bashrc` gets executed every time you bring up a terminal window.

Comment: I gave that a shot and I'm still getting the same problem