# Laravel homestead command does not work on restart

Tags: shell, laravel, command, vagrant, homestead

I have successfully installed homestead on my mac machine and i have set path using following command

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

but every time when i restart my machine, homestead command does not work, i would have to run `export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` again to fix this.

Please suggest a way to fix this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell provisioner to put that line either in /etc/profile (for the whole system) or just ~vagrant/.profile (for just your user). Like so:

```
config.vm.provision "set-path", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "grep "~/.composer/vendor/bin" ~vagrant/.profile &> /dev/null || echo "export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:\$PATH" >> ~vagrant/.profile"
end
```

This does a `grep` to check to see if that text is in the file, and if that returns a non-zero result (`||`) appends that line to the end of the file.

Comment: inside your Vagrantfile, in the top-level `Vagrant.configure` block.