# How change php version in command line?

Tags: php, apache, terminal, command

I'm trying to install the composer on my website, but the server is running PHP 5.2, and the more I change my version of PHP by cpanel, it continues running PHP 5.2 on the command line.

When I run the php -v he passes me that the version of PHP is 5.2

Is there any way I can change the version of PHP in the command line? Or something like this.

Comment: You need to *install* the newest version. Do you have access to the server?

Comment: I bought a host from br.bluehost, i tried to talk with support but they are so slowly to answer, i think i have access to the server, i don't know how much.

Comment: If the above didn't work try this solution from another answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986139/how-to-change-php-version-used-by-composer

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the setup it is hard to advise you but this may work:

Usually when multiple PHP versions are present, a symlink is used to point `/usr/bin/php` to the version of PHP binary that should be active.

Firstly find out where the php executable is being picked from. This you can do by typing `which php`. This will tell you where php is being picked from.
Now go to that folder and do `ls -l` and check if the php executable is a symlink. **If it is a symlink** you can delete the symlink and create a new one in its place that points to the correct PHP version binary.

```
ln -s '<path to php binary you want>' '<path returned by which php>'
```

Comment: I don't have access to the folder where php is being picked from =/

Comment: Then your only option is to set the PATH environment variable to point to where the correct PHP binary lives. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux

Comment: I just got access the folder, and tried to do what passed me, and I made the command: `ln -s '/usr/local/altphp55/bin/php' '/usr/local/bin/php'` but did not change the version of my php. did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the output of `which php`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue
php 7 in cli, but the browser php is 5.6

I used

```
$ php5.6 <command>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1) phpbrew

2) echo "alias php='/usr/bin/`< youre php version php7.1>'`" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc