# How to use change desktop wallpaper using Python in Ubuntu 14.04 (with Unity)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I tried this code:

```
import os
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/user/Pictures/wallpapers/X")
```

where `user` is my name and `X` is the picture.

But instead of changing the background to the given picture, it set the default Ubuntu wallpaper.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, make sure the file path is correct. Execute this line in a terminal:

```
ls /home/user/Pictures/wallpapers/X
```

Did the file get listed? If so, move on to the next step.

Make sure that you know where the `gsettings` command is. In the terminal, run:

```
which gsettings
```

That should get you the full path to `gsettings`. If nothing is displayed, the directory containing `gsettings` isn't in [your `$PATH` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux).

Let's say the path is `/usr/bin/gsettings`.
Try to execute this in a terminal:

```
/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /home/user/Pictures/wallpapers/X
```

If it works, pass the same string to `os.system()`:

```
import os
os.system("/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /home/user/Pictures/wallpapers/X")
```

Comment: when I run it in python the output  is 0 but nothing happen

Comment: Did you try it out on the command line? If it works there, it should work in Python.

Comment: Please see my revised answer for information on checking the file path and the `gsettings` path. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:/home/user/Pictures/wallpapers/picture_name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("DISPLAY=:0 GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://{0}".format(picture_path), shell=True)
```

it will works even when you use it in cron. I'v written a script that download bing images and then set as wallpaper.

also you could try the following commands:

```
feh --bg-fill picture_path
hsetroot  -extend  picture_path
```

Answer (score 1):

To **set** a specific wallpaper, the command is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/user/Pictures/wallpapers/apple.jpg'
```

The command to see (**get**) what is the current wallpaper:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```