# Install node.js on android natively

Tags: android, linux, node.js

I'm not sure about title, but here's my problem. I want nodejs binary to be avaliable on my device as system app so I could open terminal app, and just type `node app.js` to launch my node app.

*The following is done on Nexus 9 tablet under Android 6.0.0*

To to achieve this, I installed debian in chroot using [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy&hl=en) app. I managed to successfully download Node sources and install everything needed for building a binary. Then I did a configure/make/make install thing and finally had Node work in this environment.

Last step was copying everything to actual environment. I copied everything I knew: `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, `/usr/local/include` (not sure if needed) to `/system/usr` on a device and did `chmod +x node`

At this point things look pretty nice

```
root@flounder_lte:/system/usr/local/bin # ls -la
-rwxrw-rw- root     root     15386988 2015-12-04 13:26 node
-rwxrw-rw- root     root         2000 2015-12-04 13:26 npm
```

But when I try to execute node, I get the following error

```
root@flounder_lte:/system/usr/local/bin # ./node
tmp-mksh: ./node: No such file or directory
```

Why is that and what does it mean and what am I supposed to do in this situation?

Comment: That at least means it isn't in your PATH

Comment: @cricket_007 calling `./node` explicitly didn't help either : `tmp-mksh: ./node: No such file or directory`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/2795679

Comment: Isn't that bin you are pointing at for Android, not your chroot? Same for.\node

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes,  I copied everything related to node from /usr/local in chroot to /system/usr/local on the device

Comment: How would that even work? What were you expecting to happen? You have to run node that was compiled for Debian in the Debian environment