# How to reset qmake to Qt Application

Tags: qt, unix

I am trying to use qmake, but it is currently for some reason pointing to this when I run "which qmake", /Users/adam2392/anaconda/bin/qmake

This runs Qt version 4.8 though... and I want to use Qt version 5+ which I have installed, but I can't run qmake on my application because then it doesn't register the new functionalities that version 5+ has. I was wondering how I can reset, so that when I run qmake, it uses version 5+?

Answer (score 0):

`which qmake` uses your `PATH` environment variable to find `qmake`. So your `PATH` most likely points to `/Users/adam2392/anaconda/bin` (among others). It picks up the firts `qmake` program found.

Change your `PATH` variable to add path to Qt version you wish to use in front (the one you have installed):

```
export PATH=<path to Qt5 bin folder>:$PATH
```

To change this permanently, see [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

Note: If your `PATH` variable has both the old and new Qt targets (most likely the old one appearing before the new one), removing the old one should make it work, no need to add the new one a second time.