# Having trouble getting java to work on Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

I am having trouble getting java to work. I type java -version into my terminal and get java: no such file or directory. My Mac OS X version is 10.11.1. I have the newest JDK installed 1.8.0_73 x64. I am trying to compile java files and eventually create a jar file. Tutorials just say to type in java -version. Is there something I am missing in order to use the JDK?  `Taylors-MacBook-Pro-4:~ Taylor$ java -version
-bash: java: No such file or directory`

EDIT: Echoing the $PATH gives me the following.

```
Taylors-MacBook-Pro-4:~ Taylor$ echo $PATH

Taylors-MacBook-Pro-4:~ Taylor$
```

Comment: In that case you need to set your $PATH first. Otherwise your shell doesn't know where to find binary executable files.

Comment: How to set $PATH

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your $PATH is not set properly if indeed java is installed.
Type `$ echo $PATH` and see the list. Usually java is installed at `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a JAVA_HOME issue. Type:

`$ export JAVA_HOME=<correct path to your java virtual machine home folder>`

For me it's something like:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home`