# How to set up packer PATH on Mac Unix

Tags: macos, unix, path, packer

The documentation of packer says: [Packer Setup Documentation](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/setup.html)

on how to set the PATH : [How to permanently set PATH in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

And I did add :

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/packer/
```

in my ~/.zshrc file

however, when I go to type packer on the terminal first time, the dir changes to be ~/packer and when I type packer again I get :

```
~  packer
➜  packer  packer
zsh: command not found: packer
```

Does anyone have a better clue on how to set up packer's PATH on a Macintosh Unix system?

Answer (score 1):

In `OS X` you would typically have any exports set in:

```
~/.bash_profile
```

If you already have a `.bash_profile` setup then it will override `.profile`. Since you're using `zsh` you might try putting the export in `~/.zprofile`.

Comment: on echo $PATH, I get,
/Users/user123/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/user123/packer/

Comment: @Becks: I think you need to get rid of the last thing in your `$PATH` (/Users/User123/packer). If `packer` is installed in `/usr/local/bin` then that should be all you need. Try running the command `which packer` and see what is output.

Comment: @I'L'I here: cd ~/
➜  ~  pwd
/Users/user123
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/user123/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
➜  ~  cd packer
➜  packer  which packer
packer not found
➜  packer

Comment: @Becks: The command is `which packer` all by itself. Where did you install it, that's the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding your edits to the ~/.profile file instead of ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: I don't have a profile file. I have zsh installed, hence I tried adding my edits in ~/.zshrc but that doesn't seem to work either :(  ...  I do ➜$  which zsh  and I get 
/bin/zsh

Answer (score 0):

To make the new path stick permanently you need to create a .bash_profile file in your home directory and set the path there.

1. Open terminal on Mac and write ***nano .bash_profile***.
2. Create the .bash_profile file with a command line editor called nano,If it is already exists then it will open a text editor containing path.
3. Add the path you require like:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH"
   ```
4. Save the file in nano by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and confirming the name of the file as .bash_profile by hitting enter. And the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
5. Then for checking path is set or not just write `echo $PATH` in terminal. Your path would be there in it.