# Kubernetes on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, coreos

When running the following command on kube-master (CoreOS):

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

I get following error:

> Can't find aws in PATH, please fix and retry.

I have already set PATH. Can anyopne tell which 'aws' it is searching for? Is it the aws directory in kubernetes repo directory i.e. kubernetes/cluster/aws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the [AWS CLI installation guide](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and then ensure your [PATH is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

If you set "aws" as `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER`, Kubernetes will use scripts that reside in `kubernetes/cluster/aws`. If no `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER` is set, I believe the default it to rely on `gcloud` CLI tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu OS. run the below command. it will resolve your issue.

```
apt-get install awscli
```