# Scipy cannot be imported in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use scipy in a jupyter notebook and it says I have it installed, but when I try to import it, it gives me the following error.
[image]

Any help would be great. thank you.

Comment: This answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TLDR: try this

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install scipy
```

A bit more info:

Jupyter notebooks are able to work with multiple *kernels*, which are essentially pointers to the Python (or other language) executable that the notebook uses. In a Python kernel, you can figure out which one is being used by typing

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

When you run a bash command in the notebook, like `!pip install scipy`, that uses the bash environment that was active when you launched the notebook **which is not necessarily associated with the Python kernel you are using**. That means that it may be installing scipy in a different Python location. You can figure out which Python your shell points to by running `!which python`. If this doesn't match, then `!pip install` will not be installing in the right place.

You can fix this by explicitly telling the bash prompt which Python/pip you want to use. For example, this should do the trick:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install scipy
```

This runs the pip version associated with your executable, and installs scipy with that. For some more details on what's happening behind the scenes, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths).

Answer (score 1):

The pip that you execute is using a shell that may (and that is probably the case here) have a different python interpreter than the one of the jupyter notebook!

Jake VanderPlas to the rescue https://twitter.com/jakevdp/status/841791667472543745
Do the following *in* the notebook

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

Depending on the output of "sys.executable", adjust your command-line call, still *in* the notebook

```
!/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install scipy
```

But as you have scipy installed, the issue is to understand why your anaconda scipy is not found. Do you have a default virtualenv for all your python use? How do you start the notebook?