# Facebook Chat module Installation on Python using Jupyter

Tags: python, facebook-chatbot, facebook-chat

I need the Facebook chat module to send Facebook messages using Python. In order to do it, I am using Jupyter in my notebook. Below is the code used.

---

```
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-6-3ab37e38fb81> in <module>()
  ----> 1 import fbchat

 ImportError: No module named fbchat
 File "<ipython-input-7-8dba1f7bdc0c>", line 1
     -m pip install fbchat
     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It says pip not recognized. I have also added an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JfJd.png) that shows the error.

Comment: I don't think that's how you use pip *inside* jupyter. You may want to use conda instead - depending on your set up. Have a look at https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
python -m pip install fbchat
```

is not working, try

```
pip install fbchat
```

If this also couldn't fetch fbchat, use the source to build on your machine as following:-

```
git clone git://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat.git
cd fbchat
python setup.py install
```

use admin or sudo permissions if required

Answer (score 0):

Don't use -m

Just use this on ur terminal
`pip2 install fbchat`

or 
`pip3 install fbchat`

Answer (score 0):

## Use a `!` to execute pip within the notebook:

If you are trying to use `pip` from within a Jupyter Notebook use an `!`:

```
! pip install fbchat
```