# Why am I unable to import the gensim module that has definitely been installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, gensim

I have installed the gensim module for MAC by passing the following command in my Terminal:

```
pip3 install gensim
```

I already have many other modules such as pandas and numpy that have been installed but I am able to import the same to my Jupyter Notebook without any issues.

This is how I am importing gensim:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
```

So I checked the path where the 2 modules have been installed through the terminal, these being the same for a module I am able to import such as pandas as well as for gensim.

```
pip3 show pandas
pip3 show gensim
```

In both the cases I get the same output:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue in this case?

Comment: The python in the Jupyter Notebook is different from python3.7 or it's location is different. basically you have 2 versions of python or python installed at 2 locations. one standard and one with anaconda.

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths/39022003). It has answer about how to run with specific python.