# Getting error of 'Module not found' on jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, libraries, jupyter-lab

I'm a Windows user. I have successfully imported malplotlib while I was working on on Google colaboratory a few days ago.But now,both jupyter and colab. are showing this same error when I try to import matplotlib--'No module named matplotlib'.

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, it shows---                                                                                     
 -3.8-64 *
 -3.8-32

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Jupyter with multiple Python and IPython paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths)

Comment: Yess. It has solved my problem. Thanks:)