# Jupyter notebook Python kernel - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory python3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

## Question

In Jupyter notebook, how to solve the issue of Python interpreter not found.

### Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Anaconda environment with Python 3.7

### Problem

Start a jupyter notebook and create a notebook with Python 3 kernel and get the error. **nlp_in_tensorflow** was a conda environment already removed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 185, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 313, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 220, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 131, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/user/conda/envs/cs231n/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/conda/envs/nlp_in_tensorflow/bin/python3': '/home/user/conda/envs/nlp_in_tensorflow/bin/python3'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cause

The kernel.json file of the Python 3 kernel was pointing to the deleted environment.

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /home/oonisim/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

$ cat ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json 
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/user/conda/envs/nlp_in_tensorflow/bin/python3",   <----- Referring to the deleted environment
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

### Resource

- [What to do when things go wrong - Python Environments](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#python-environments)

> Multiple python environments, whether based on Anaconda or Python
> Virtual environments, are often the source of reported issues. **In many
> cases, these issues stem from the Notebook server running in one
> environment, while the kernel and/or its resources, derive from
> another environment**.
>
> **Another thing to check is the kernel.json file that will be located in
> the aforementioned kernel specs directory identified by running
> jupyter kernelspec list**. This file will contain an argv stanza that
> includes the actual command to run when launching the kernel.
> Oftentimes, when reinstalling python environments, a previous
> kernel.json will reference an python executable from an old or
> non-existent location. As a result, it’s always a good idea when
> encountering kernel startup issues to validate the argv stanza to
> ensure all file references exist and are appropriate.

### Fix

Removed ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json.

### Related issues

- [Jupyter Notebook is loading incorrect Python kernel #2563](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2563)
- [Running Jupyter with multiple Python and IPython paths - 3. How Jupyter knows what Python to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths)

> Jupyter is set-up to be able to use a wide range of "kernels", or
> execution engines for the code. These can be Python 2, Python 3, R,
> Julia, Ruby... there are dozens of possible kernels to use. But in
> order for this to happen, Jupyter needs to know where to look for the
> associated executable: that is, it needs to know which path the python
> sits in.
>
> These paths are specified in jupyter's kernelspec, and it's possible
> for the user to adjust them to their desires. For example, here's the
> list of kernels that I have on my system: