# Can't use Matplotlib and Numpy on Jupyter Notebook (ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'numpy')

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've been unsuccessfully trying to run **Matplotlib** and **Numpy** on Jupyter Notebook. I imagine that something went wrong during the installation, but I've already tried to uninstall/update and nothing has changed. I'm new at it and I've seen other questions similar to mine, but I still can't solve this problem.

On jupyter, the error message I got was: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'. Traceback (most recent call last)  in </module/>**

I have installed python3 and the libraries manually on the terminal using the command:

*brew install python3*

*pip3 install numpy*

*pip3 install Matplotlib*

As I'm using Anaconda to run my Jupyter notebook, I've also installed miniconda and tried:

*conda install numpy*

*conda install Matplotlib*

Also, if I run the command *pip3 list* I can clearly see that numpy, Matplotlib and conda are already installed as a package.
My current version of **python is 3.9.**, **numpy is 1.19.4**,  **matplotlib is 3.3.2**.

I have no more ideas about what to do and why Jupyter is not importing those libraries. Any help will be very useful. I use MacOS system.

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment, you will have to start your jupyter notebook also in this virtual environment

Comment: This answer, while a bit verbose, should help you figure out what's going on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths/39022003#39022003