# How to deal with ImportError: cannot import name 'pytree' from 'jaxlib' of using jax?

Tags: python, ubuntu, importerror, jax

I have installed jax and jaxlib using pip according to https://github.com/google/jax#installation:

```
Successfully installed jax-0.1.68 jaxlib-0.1.67+cuda11
```

But after i ran my project, it showed Importerror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1, in <module>
    from jax import jit, jacfwd, jacrev, hessian, lax
  File "...", line 16, in <module>
    from .api import (
  File "...", line 38, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "...", line 30, in <module>
    from . import dtypes
  File "...", line 31, in <module>
    from .lib import xla_client
  File "...", line 51, in <module>
    from jaxlib import pytree
ImportError: cannot import name 'pytree' from 'jaxlib' (/home/control/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jaxlib/__init__.py)
```

Could this problem comes from uncompatible jax/jaxlib version for running the project?
If not, how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are importing a much older jax version than you report in the question; `jax.lib` has not attempted to import `pytree` from `jaxlib` since version 0.2.8.

This probably indicates that you are running `pip install` in a different environment than the one you're using to execute code.

Assuming you are working at the command prompt, try this instead:

```
$ python -m pip install jax jaxlib
$ python -c "import jax; print(jax.__version__)"
```

(where you can replace `python` in both lines with whatever python executable you are using)

If you're working in Jupyter with different kernels, this answer might help you understand how to proceed: [Running Jupyter with multiple Python and IPython paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007571/running-jupyter-with-multiple-python-and-ipython-paths)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and heads up. yes the right version that is installed is jax-0.1.68 and jaxlib-0.1.67+cuda11, since the project is built upon it.

Comment: The author of that github project told me that the project may be not runnable with new jax version: https://github.com/YukunXia/Carla_iLQR_MPC/issues/3. i installed the new version jax as you mentioned, and it brings ValueError:

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/control/Documents/Carla projects/Carla_iLQR_MPC/MPC/ilqr_jax_MPC.py", line 164, in <module>
    jac_l, hes_l, jac_l_final, hes_l_final, jac_f = derivative_init()
  File "/home/control/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/core.py", line 981, in concrete_aval
    raise TypeError(f"Value {repr(x)} with type {type(x)} is not a valid JAX "
TypeError: Value <CompiledFunction of <function jacfwd.<locals>.jacfun at 0x7ff1f81c07a0>> with type <class 'CompiledFunction'> is not a valid JAX type

Comment: Could that be the case which the project really not works with new version? thanks for your time.

Comment: *with new version of jax

Comment: jax 0.1.68 is not compatible with jaxlib 0.1.67; the latter was released a full year after the former. You'll have to use something like jaxlib 0.1.50 which you can install with `pip install jax==0.1.68 jaxlib==0.1.50 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html`

Comment: thank you here again.