# unable to import PyPDF2 Python 3.11

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter, pypdf, python-3.11

I have been trying many solutions: but I cannot import PyPDF2 yet.

I got the following error.
I have already check if the version is right and it says it is already satisfied.
I changed the computer twice and used Jupyter notebook and Pycharm alternatively. I am not sure what is wrong. I can import other moduels.

```
Command Line error
C:\Users\taye>python3.11 -m pip install PyPDF2
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in c:\users\taye\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (3.0.1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
**ERROR MESSAGE
**
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import PyPDF2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

Comment: It's quite likely that your Jupyter installation is using a different Python from your command line.  you need to install this package through Jupter.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that your notebook and your PyPDF2 library are in 2 different Python environments.

Quick and easy solution:

Use the `!pip install PyPDF2` command to install it in the Jupyter Notebook environment

Read this link for other (maybe better) solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022003/12451082

https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/