Jax Circular Import - partially initialized module 'jax' has no attribute 'version'
I've installed jax using pip3 install jax, and have also tried pip install -U "jax[cpu]". When I attempt to import jax in a Jupyter notebook, as follows:
from jax import numpy as np
import jax

I get the following error:

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'jax' has no attribute
'version' (most likely due to a circular import)

Has anyone else had a similar problem, or have a solution? Thanks!

This generally comes up as a result of version skew between the jax package and the jaxlib package.
There's no one-size-fits-all method of fixing it, because such version skew can appear in one of several ways.
First, you should first make sure that the jax and jaxlib versions installed in your Python environment match. One way to do this is by running (on a linux/osx command line):
$ python -m pip list | grep jax
jax                           0.4.28
jaxlib                        0.4.28

If these match and you're still having issues, then it's possible that you have a local file named jax.py that is being imported rather than the jax package. If so, delete it.
If this is not the issue, then it could be that your PYTHONPATH is set in such a way that your import path is hitting different versions than pip imports. You can check this by running
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)

This shows you the list of directories, in order, on your system where Python will look when you type import jax. Check the contents of each of these to make sure the first jax your system finds is the one you expect it to find.
Another scenario I've seen is when running code in a Jupyter notebook: if you've updated jax or jaxlib during the course of a session and not restarted the runtime, then it can lead to this kind of version skew. The fix is to restart your jupyter notebook runtime after installing new packages.
Another possibility if using Jupyter is that the python executable associated with your pip install command is different than the python executable associated with your Jupyter notebook kernel. For some discussion of how to debug this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022003/2937831.
Hopefully one of those tips matches what's going on in your case, and you can fix your problem!
