# How do you make a script so that all commands in /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, and /usr/sbin are set as aliases?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Currently, I'm on RHEL4. For some reason, none of my commands have aliases set by default, and it's becoming a huge pain to add everything I need in bashrc. Is there a way to  transfer all my executables as aliases?

Comment: What do you mean with _none of my commands have aliases set by default_? Does it mean that you have to use the full path for every command? If so, the problem has to do with your `$PATH` variable not containing these paths.

Comment: Oh, is this solved by adding /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin into $PATH?

Comment: If what I said before is the case... Yes! Check [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux). The PATH should be set in `/etc/environment`, but there may be issues.

Comment: I think your real problem is that you are lacking basic knowledge about the OS you intend to use. You better step back, and fetch some good book about Linux; and start reading that front to cover.