# Python Command Line Application without running the command starting with python <filename>

Tags: python

I have a command line app that I want to deploy. The only problem is that to run it you have to run the python file like this: `

```
$python application.py <arguement>
```

`. I have seen other applications made in python that can run like this but would require this input

```
$application<arguement>
```

How can I make this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing it in bash (Linux) or similar, then have the first line of your source (.py) file as

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

(depending on the location of your Python interpreter) or possibly

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then make the script executable

```
$ chmod +x foo
```

and make sure the directory is in your `$PATH` or explicitly specify the directory in your command e.g.

```
./foo
```

Comment: OP is not asking about running python script in windows or linux and making the script as executable.

Comment: This is exactly what I want but what do you mean make it executable?

Comment: Executable files (programs) in Linux have a special flag (x) to dstinguish them. The chmod +x sets this flag so the system will attempt to execute the program if you ask it to. I suggest you go and read a tutorial on the Linux file system and how file permissions work.

Comment: Ok so it worked but I have to do ./<filename>.py. Is there a way to only have to do <filename> <arguement>? Also, I can only use it in the directory where my file is. Is there a way to make it usable everywhere?

Comment: Assuming you are using Linx/bash, make sure that the directory in which the Python scripts is on your $PATH (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path). That way, assuming there is nothing with the same name before it on your $PATH it should execute for you anywhere.

Comment: Also, you don't need the .py extension at the end of the file. (Note, though, that a lot of editors wont recognise your program as Python source code if you do and so won't highlight keywords etc).

Comment: Ok so it worked but when I quit the terminal and open it again I need to run:  export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/bin" again. How can I make it permanent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux