# Cassandra nodetool error

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have a Cassandra cluster of two nodes. I am using Cassandra 3.10.

when I tried to run `nodetool status`, by default it is calling `/usr/bin/nodetool` and gives result `You must set the CASSANDRA_CONF and CLASSPATH vars`. 
`CASSANDRA_HOME` and `CASSANDRA_HOME/bin` is already set in bashrc.

When I run `CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/nodetool status` It is showing correct result, both the nodes are up.

My problem is how can I make `CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/nodetool` as default. So that I can call it from any where.

PS: `cqlsh` is also showing same behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `CASSANDRA_HOME/bin` as Environment `PATH`

Comment: Environment PATH : In /etc/environment file?

Comment: Using linux right ?

Comment: yes, centOS 6.9.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux

Comment: As in question also I have mentioned that CASSANDRA_HOME/bin is already set in my bashrc. However I am able to manage it by prepending it in PATH variable instead of appending like. 
export PATH=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin:$PATH      (I hope there should not be any side effect of this)

Comment: Don't forget to `SOURCE` the file