# Nmap install unproperly

Tags: ubuntu, nmap

I am trying to install Nmap-7.5 with source installation and the Compiler says :

```
NMAP SUCCESSFULLY INSTALLED
```

but when I use the command: `nmap -v` ,the system says command not found

I find the Nmap has been installed as `/usr/local/bin/nmap`

When I want to use the Namp, I have to enter the path `/usr/local/bin/nmap`and give the command like `./nmap -v`.
I want to use the command like `nmap-v`,but I don't known how.
THANKS!

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `/usr/local/bin/` is missing from PATH. You can check it with `echo $PATH` command.
To add it to path use instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux).
Alternatively you can create an alias for `nmap` by editing the `~/.bashrc` file:
1. Add the following line into file:

```
alias nmap='/usr/local/bin/nmap'
```

2. Source from this file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```