# How to change PATH variable permanently in solaris 10?

Tags: solaris-10

I'm using solaris 10 vm box, every time I login or open new terminal my PATH variable is getting reset to default, I'm using export PATH=XXX command to set my path. When I tried to change the content in /etc/skel/local.profile file changes are not getting accepted even after I set them to 777 with chmod, same when I tried to change the login file in /etc/default, and there is no file or directory named environment in /etc/ directory currently my shell shows bash. Can someone help to permanently change the PATH variable without setting it for every session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/skel` folder is only used when you create a new user, its content is copied to the new user's home folder.

If you want to change the `PATH` variable everytime you login to your account, then add the following to the `.profile` file in your home folder (create it if it doesn't already exist):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/some/new/path
```

Comment: @Pavanisivadath have you tried logged out and logged in again (not just starting a terminal)? if it doesn't work try putting the line in `.bash_profile` in your home folder.

Comment: yes I've logged out and logged in again .there is no such file in my home directory.

Comment: This answer is correct and works perfectly, thanks so much @GregDepoire-Ferrer ! :)