# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pipfile' for pipenv install requests

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to follow this guide on pipenv and virtualenv: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ . The problem is, I run into a problem when trying to `$ pipenv install requests` (which in my case I think should be `$python3 -m pipenv install requests` since simply `pipenv` returns command not found.)

Why is permission denied?

I'm a terminal noob so bear with me.

```
$ pip3 install --user pipenv

$ python3 -m pipenv

Usage: __main__.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

$ python3 -m pipenv install requests

Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    cli()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 895, in install
    ensure_project(three=three, python=python)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 180, in ensure_project
    ensure_pipfile(validate=validate)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 141, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 219, in create_pipfile
    self.write_toml(data, 'Pipfile')
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 226, in write_toml
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pipfile'
```

Comment: try with `sudo`

Comment: I've heard that that is bad practice.

Comment: and have you tried with `apt-get install python-YourPackage`

Comment: @Sandi `sudo` runs the app in root mode. You can use `sudo` unless or otherwise you are aware of what you are doing. Otherwise, it may harm the core.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing, so it feels like a bad idea using `sudo`. If you think it's okay in this case I'd be glad to know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you've added the [UserBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE)'s bin directory to your path (follow the Note box at the [documentation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs#installing-pipenv) you were following to see how to do this).

The third command you mentioned should just be: `pipenv install requests`.

---

Longer version:

I'll go a little more in depth for some of the command line concepts since you're getting started with the command line (and for others who would like a little more in depth reference).

You show three commands:

- `pip3 install --user pipenv`
- This is perfect, it installs *pipenv* as a user package (not avalible to the entire system)
- `python3 -m pipenv`
- This doesn't do anything.  What you see returned is a "[Usage message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message)". It's saying this command expects some main.py program, options (optional because in parenthesis), a command (mandatory) and potentially more arguments. If you see a usage message it means you did not call that program the way its author intended.
- `python3 -m pipenv install requests`
- This should just be `pipenv install requests`. But it won't work until you've added UserBase's bin to your path (you'll get a `pipenv: command not found` error).

Your [`PATH`](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) is where your shell will search for the command you've listed. See changing your path on [Mac or Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux/14638025#14638025) or [Windows](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path).

As the [documentation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs#installing-pipenv) you were following mentions, you want to run `python3 -m site`, you'll get output something like the following:

```
$ python -m site
  .
  .
  .
USER_BASE: '/Users/<myusername>/Library/Python/3.6' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/<myusername>/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Now that you know where your `USER_BASE` is, add a `/bin` onto the end and add it to your PATH.  Again see OS specific instructions but on OSX you can add `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/<myusername>/Library/Python/3.6/bin` to your `~/.profile`, run `source ~/.profile`, and your shell will now search that directory when you enter the command `pipenv`.

Comment: Trying to follow this advice and got USER_BASE as follows: `USER_BASE: '/home/<myusername>/.local' (exists)` without mention of any `/Library/Python/3.x`.  Is there a solution for those in this case?  How do you get `/Library/Python/3.x`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptoms:

```
with open(path, 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pipfile'
```

the problem was that I had a `Pipfile` in one of the parent directories and with different permissions (in my case, created by `root` while experimenting). Deleting this `Pipfile` resolved the issue. The same issue is discussed [Pipenv issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1102).

More details: when trying to install/create a new virtual environment, pipenv looks into all the parent directories to see if there already is a `Pipfile` in there. If there is a `Pipfile`, and was created with different permissions (e.g. under `root` via `sudo` in my case), pipenv will not have permissions to write to this `Pipfile`, creating a somewhat unclear error message.

A tell tale sing is that `pipenv --where` prints a different directory name than you'd expect (or prints a directory path when you're just creating a new environment instead of "No pipfile present at project home...")