# How to enable autocomplete/tab for directories linked to unix PATH?

Tags: bash, unix

I just followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux) to be able to permanently access a directory from anywhere in terminal after setting it to `PATH` by adding:

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir` to **`~/.bash_profile`**

I am now able to access a script anywhere in terminal with `bash update_git_script.sh` but am no longer able to type `bash upd` + `tab` as I was before when I was in the actual directory containing the script.

The main reason I've made the scripts I'm trying to access is to quickly pull different git repos, so being able to use `tab` to complete the item is ideal.

Thanks

Comment: This Q  **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: why not `upd<TAB>` since you've added the path to `PATH`?