# What does Mysql -u root mean?

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql in /usr/local/ directory. But when I try to use the server by typing mysql -u root it says '/usr/local/bin/mysql: No such file or directory'. I could understand that it looks in a different directory. But how to change it? Or should I have to install mysql in that directory? In which case, mysql installer does not allow me to change the directory as well.

Answer (score 4):

When you type a command name without a path on a Unix-like shell, the shell looks for something of that name in every directory listed in your `$PATH` environment variable, in order.

You can see the contents of that with

```
echo $PATH
```

They are colon-separated.

If you want to add another directory to it (such as `/usr/local/bin`, which you'd need in this case), have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix) or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path). You could also just run that binary directly by running `/usr/local/bin/mysql -u root`.

---

But this is nothing to do with the title of your question. To answer that, see the man page of mysql, which says:

> ```
>   ·   --user=user_name, -u user_name
>
>       The MySQL user name to use when connecting to the server
> ```

In other words, that is setting the user to be `root`, for purposes of authenticating with the database server. Note that this doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the `root` Unix user.