# 'command not found' though pylint appears to be installed

Tags: package, installation, pylint

I ran `pip install --user pylint`
without getting any error, but I get `pylint: command not found` when I try `pylint foo.py` although there is a directory `/Users/erc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pylint` containing what I would guess are all the necessary files (although no `pylint.py` but maybe the `__main__.py` or `__ini__.py` are there for that).  Also, I get nothing with`which pylint`.

What can I try?

Comment: What is the output of running `which pylint` in your shell?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl As I explain, the output is... nothing!  I type `which pylint` press enter, and I get a new line with a new prompt.

Comment: That means that `pylint` is not on your path. You'll need to add the containing folder to your path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix

Comment: I tried adding the folder`/Users/erc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pylint` to my `PATH` variable, but again `which pylint` returns nothing.  I notice that this is a *folder*, and that there is no executable.  What exactly happens when I run `pylint foo.py`?

Comment: So I can use `pylint` by running `python -m pylint foo.py` by following [this note for Windows users](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/installation.html) (I am on a mac...) Also, up on that page there is the instruction to install from source distribution: `python setup.py install`, which I presume would create `pylint.py`?  At any rate, I *don't* have `setup.py`, which probably should have been installed, but I didn't get any error message when running `pip install....` I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which files get installed when \`pip\` installing \`pylint\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358987/which-files-get-installed-when-pip-installing-pylint)

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue even though I had pylint as well as pip installed. The issue is because the path is not pointing to the place where these libraries are present.
eg: my path - programs/python/python35/ and whereas my pip and pylint were installed in programs/python/python35/Scripts.
So when I added the path to environment variable it worked.