# Flutter install on google pixelbook

Tags: flutter

I am installing flutter on my google pixelbook and have run into an error.

I followed the steps on this article: 
https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-development-on-a-pixelbook-dde984a3fc1e

I know this is experimental at this time but I am completely new to pixelbook and linux so I thought I would see if anyone has run into this error before. When I run flutter doctor I get this error in terminal:

> $ flutter doctor --v
>   -bash: flutter: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't added Flutter to your path?

Flutter is in the ~/flutter/bin path if you followed the instructions here: https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-development-on-a-pixelbook-dde984a3fc1e

Comment: I did add it to the path. I got flutter doctor to work but after a restart the flutter command doesn’t work again . Do I have to run those commands every time I want to work on an app?

Comment: Im also running into issues trying to run these Sudo commands :

Comment: chronos@localhost / $ sudo crossystem dev_boot_signed_only=0
chronos@localhost / $ sudo /usr/libexec/debugd/helpers/dev_features_rootfs_verification
chronos@localhost / $ sudo reboot

Comment: Hi Sam, you'll need to add the path to your profile if you want it to be loaded each time. That's outside the scope of this answer, but more info is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix. As for the other commands, you'll need to explain what error you're getting for anyone to help you.