# Install java Open JDK 10 on AWS linux

Tags: java, solr

How do I setup https://jdk.java.net/10/ so Solr 7.5 can find it under the installation?

I am using linux Amazon Linux 2 AMI 2.0.20181008 x86_64 HVM gp2.

Questions

- In what directory should I put the files. ex. /usr/local/java?
- Where should I set JAVA_HOME so every user will get it also after a reboot.
- Where should I set the path to java so every user will get it also after a reboot.

Comment: I would suggest JDK 11.0.1 as JDK 10 is done.

Comment: On https://jdk.java.net/10/ there are two GA releases 10 and 11. Why do you think that v10 is dead? I know that Solr should work with 10 but not 11

Comment: It still works but is no longer maintained by Oracle, even with commercial support https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any installation location should work as long as you set the correct JAVA_HOME path and add the binary path to your $PATH variable.

You can configure both globally by editing `/etc/environment`, which should take effect for all users after restarting your shell (you can shortcut that process by doing `source /etc/environment` when testing).

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre_10....
```

There should already be a PATH entry there which you can modify to add the Java binary directory.

This can differ between different Linux distributions and shell versions. If your distribution (Amazon Linux used it earlier at least) doesn't support it, you [can use /etc/profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix).

Another option that many prefer is to add an executable shell script in /etc/profile.d/ that sets up the variables for you, as these scripts are invoked on each initialization of a shell for all users.