# Apache version viewer command httpd is not working

Tags: apache, redhat

/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -v  command is working on my server but 
httpd -v is not working. it says command not found.How can i fix this so that httpd -v show me the apache version.

Comment: Add `httpd` to *PATH*?

Comment: While I am adding path its working in a temporary basis,while I am restarting the server its not working

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix.