# How to create an environment variable in Qt Installer framework regardless of OS

Tags: qt, qtscript, qt-installer

How can I add a new Environment Variable to the Qt installer. I know that it should go in the .qs script something like the following:

```
var path = installer.environmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + installer.value("TargetDir");
component.addElevatedOperation("EnvironmentVariable","PATH",path,true);
```

I'm trying the above on Linux, but it's complaining about `EnvironmentVariable` not existing when I install my program.

Comment: As specified in the [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/operations.html#summary-of-operations), this is currently only supported on windows. You will have perform that step manually on linux. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/3767076 to get started

Answer (score 0):

Well this operation is only supported on windows, but you can try do this:

```
component.addElevatedOperation("AppendFile", "/etc/environment", "export PATH=\"$PATH;@TargetDir@\"\n");
```

**Warning:** do this only on installation process

```
if (installer.isInstaller()) {
     [...]
}
```

If this runs on unistallation, maybe can delete other things of `/etc/environment`