# FuzzywuzzyR error attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

I am trying to test example code for `fuzzywuzzyR`, but I receive the error message:

> Error in init$Extract(string = word, sequence_strings = choice,
>   processor = PROC,  : attempt to apply non-function.

I read a few things online that talked about having the correct version of python installed. When I check in R, mine says python 2.7. However, I am not familiar with python as I only use R. Do I need python for this? How can I change the version. An answer online said " As a quick fix, I changed the PATH variables to python 3.5 location and used pip to install Levenshtein and fuzzywuzzy. If R instance was running during this operation, then close and reopen R." But I don't know what this means - how do I change the PATH variable?

```
library(fuzzywuzzyR)

word = "new york jets"

choice = c("Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys")

init_proc = FuzzUtils$new()
PROC = init_proc$Full_process
PROC1 = tolower

init_scor = FuzzMatcher$new()
SCOR = init_scor$WRATIO
init <- FuzzExtract$new()
init$Extract(string = word, sequence_strings = choice, processor = PROC, scorer = SCOR)
```

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: re PATH: in case you use Windows: [for Win10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/set-path-environment-variables-in-windows-10/). For Unix/Linux [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix) might help.

Comment: No I'm using a mac

Comment: @Caroline, I ported the fuzzywuzzy python library to R. You need to have python configured in your operating system and the error you receive appears when a user hasn't configured python correctly. There is a similar issue on the [Github package repository](https://github.com/mlampros/fuzzywuzzyR/issues/1). Feel free to open a new issue (if the previous issues are not helpful) by giving more details on the [R package repository](https://github.com/mlampros/fuzzywuzzyR/issues).