# How to fix: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library - Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, cx-oracle

I am establishing a connection to oracle 11g which is in a remote server using cx_oracle 7 with python 3.6.7. my OS in Ubuntu 18.04

I have installed oracle instant client library with libclntsh.so but I am not getting the expected output.

here is the code which i am using to connect to the oracle db

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@host/port")
print (connection.version)
connection.close()
```

when the script runs i expect to get the connection version instead i am getting the following error message

> File "script.py", line 13, in 
>       connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@host/port") cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle
>   Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory". See
>   https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help

Comment: (i) Use [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) instead of the older cx_Oracle.  (ii) python-oracledb by default runs in a "Thin mode" that doesn't need Oracle Client libraries so you won't get DPI-1047 (iii) Review [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After some more research i got the solution from [Ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client) , after you have installed oracle instant-client you will have to integrate oracle libraries as follows:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/`<version>`/client(64)/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
>
> An example for 12.1 version for Linux x86_64 can be:
>
> export
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

where `<version>`  indicates the version of your of your oracle instant-client  e.g 11.2,  12.2 
The connection  parameter should be as follows

`connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username/password@host/service_name e.g orcl")`

to get the listener/service_name type the following in the oracle sqlplus

```
SQL> show parameter local_listener
```

literal under VALUE is your listener/service_name.

Comment: For installing Oracle Instant Client, I can advise to follow this [guide](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html) instead (download a package and unzip it into /opt/oracle/). Also, I think it would better add [permanent paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/9160102)

Comment: Generally it's better to use `ldconfig` instead of setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  This is recommended in the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).

Comment: Worked for me but instead of using the zip files, on Ubuntu I used the rpm file and then installed it using 'alien':
alien -i oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Then I had to add the library :
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

Comment: when adding the library you should not use brackets in the path at: client(64). So simple use: .../client64/...

Answer (score 18):

I was facing the exact same problem. This is what worked for me:

- First, I downloaded the Oracle *Basic* [zip file](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html). In my case, I got the 64-bit version.
- After that, I unzipped it in an **opt** directory. I had to use *sudo* in my system

```
    $ sudo mkdir -p /opt/oracle  

    $ cd /opt/oracle  

    $ sudo unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

- Then I installed *libaio1*. Note that I am working with Ubuntu

```
    $ sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

- Finally, I added the path to the external variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
    $ vim ~/.bashrc
```

- And added this line to the `.bashrc` file

```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_8:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

- After saving the `.bashrc` file, I sourced it:

```
    $ source ~/.bashrc
```

Then my Python script worked nicely again.

See also the **cx_oracle** [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html)

Comment: If you have no other Oracle software, (and have root access) I'd recommend using `ldconfig` (see the cx_Oracle install doc) instead of setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  The latter may not propagate to your process in all cases, e.g through a webserver

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestion, @ChristopherJones

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS server what worked for me (which may be obvious but wasn't to me!) is 1) when you perform the export, you need to be in the folder you intend to run the app/ command connecting to Oracle from, and although this worked, after closing the SSH terminal to the EC2 server, was then not available again which was resolved by 2) Add it to ~/.bashrc
Steps in full:

With the Oracle instant client unzipped in for example: /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_9

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
cd ~/your-project-folder
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_9
```

I then added to ~/.bashrc with:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

And add this line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_9
```

And in the terminal run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Mine worked as expected installed on an EC2 server under 'ubuntu' user with requisite nvm/ nodeJs installed

In nodeJs an example connection might look something like:

```
const testOracleConnection = async () => {
    let conn;

    try {
        conn = await oracledb.getConnection(oracleConfig);

        const query1 = 'select ID, anotherColumn from someTable where ID = 1111';

        const result = await conn.execute(query1);

        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            try {
                await conn.close();
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I have almost given up on this error. I tried potentially all the solution on the internet and nothing worked.

I was writing a similar script in Unix where I was getting the same error. I have applied the same fix that I used in shell script and it worked like charm.

The Python script worked fine accessing DB via cx_Oracle if I execute it directly. But when I schedule it through crontab I was constantly getting the error "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047"

Here is the fix. Import the OS module and add the below code.

os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = "Your oracle lib ". In my case it is /u01/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/

Comment: This is a common crontab behavior.  Generally I'd recommend setting  the environment variables (ORACLE_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc) in a shell script and then invoking Python from that script.  Your crontab would invoke the shell script. Setting Oracle environment variables inside running Python programs causes problems for the unwary.  Note you are using libraries from an ORACLE_HOME install, whereas the other answers on this question all use Instant Client, so they don't need the ORACLE_HOME variable set.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with Debian 10 image version with python, I had followed below steps to resolve my docker image issue:

Step1 : downloaded oracle-instantclient19.19-basic-19.19.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm from [Oracle official site](https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html):

Step 2: Installed in the base image

Step 3: I had setup following ENV variables:

ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.19/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib

This resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
apt install libaio1
echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_8 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle- instantclient.conf
ldconfig
pip install cx_Oracle
```

It work for me after search in google 2 day and try more 10 solution

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo su
mkdir -p /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/19800/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
apt install libaio1
echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_8 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf
ldconfig
pip install cx_Oracle
exit
```

Comment: An alternative is to use the RPM packages so that install is simply `alien -i --scripts oracle-instantclient19.22-basic-19.22.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm && apt-get install libaio1`. But the first step would be to use [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) instead of the older cx_Oracle.  Python-oracledb doesn't need Instant Client for most people.

Answer (score -2):

If you're working with aws lambdas to connect to your RDS/OracleDB, then try this approach using Docker to automated the build for the aws lambda layer - https://medium.com/@sabithvm/building-up-on-lambda-layers-a4771d3b9c7

Comment: You are not answering the question with your response.