# Linux. Connect ot Oracle. cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047 Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so

Tags: python, linux, oracle, cx-oracle

I have error "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help"

I saw https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#oracle-instant-client-zip and [How to fix: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823744/how-to-fix-cx-oracle-databaseerror-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-cli)

I always work on Windows and only learing on Linux system. I need help for this issue. Connect to Oracle from python:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('<USER>/<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>/<SID>')
```

I never connected from Linux. It's first time.

```
user@postgresql:~/opt$ cd oracle
user@postgresql:~/opt/oracle$ unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
Archive:  instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
inflating: instantclient_12_2/adrci  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/BASIC_README  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/genezi  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libclntshcore.so.12.1  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.so.12.1  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libipc1.so  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libmql1.so  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libnnz12.so  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libocci.so.12.1  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libociei.so  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libocijdbc12.so  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/libons.so  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/liboramysql12.so  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/ojdbc8.jar  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/uidrvci  
inflating: instantclient_12_2/xstreams.jar
user@postgresql:~$ sudo apt install libaio1
user@postgresql:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo nano oracle-instantclient.conf
user@postgresql:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo ldconfig
user@postgresql:/etc/ld.so.conf.d$ sudo export 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Linux

```
user@postgresql:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.3.0-46-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-003) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)) #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 17:37:05 UTC 2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Maybe It will be hlepfully:
download rpm(oracle-instantclient12.2-basic, oracle-instantclient12.2-devel, oracle-instantclient12.2-devel).

of course, needs only oracle-instantclient12.2

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.*
```

Need only add to PATH:

```
user@postgresql:~$export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
user@postgresql:~$sudo ldconfig
user@postgresql:~$ sudo nano  /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh && sudo chmod o+r /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin
```

Comment: Never set ORACLE_HOME for Instant Client.  It's not an Oracle home installation.  Just set your library search path, preferably with `ldconfig` as you did, and as shown in these [Linux x64 Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).  WIth this set, you don't need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Also, you should use 19c which is really the renamed terminal release of the 12c line.  It connects to the same DB versions as the 12.2 Instant Client.

Comment: @Christopher Jones, Thank you. I surprised, that no word about ORACLE_HOME in instruction. Now, it's understand. Tell me, please,  need in "PATH"  write path to instantclient?

Comment: On Linux you only need PATH if you have installed the tools with binaries.  (With a special exception that the 19c sqlplus RPM package will create a link so PATH isn't needed just for that binary)

Comment: @ Christopher Jones Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For WSL Ubuntu

1. you are going to download zip version for the instantclient-basic and the instantclient-sqlplus for linux from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html
2. create a folder called /opt/oracle

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle/
```

3. now install zip and libaio1

```
apt-get install zip libaio1
cd /opt/oracle/
```

4. Unzip the instantclient basic, and sqlplus version to the created oracle folder.

```
unzip /location/to/your/download/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
unzip /location/to/your/download/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
```

5. change directory to instantclient_12_2

```
cd instantclient_12_2/
```

6. run the following commands

```
ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so
ln -s libocci.so.12.1 libocci.so
```

7. edit the .bashrc file to set oracle home.

```
sudo nano $HOME/.bashrc
```

8. Add the following lines to the end of .bashrc

```
# set oracle home at the end of the file
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH
```

9. And

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

10. Finally, install cx_Oracle

Comment: Does this not work with a more recent Oracle Client library, such as 21.3?

Comment: I think, working, but I don't try. I will try and add to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with Debian 10 image version with python, I had followed below steps to resolve my docker image issue:

Step1 : downloaded oracle-instantclient19.19-basic-19.19.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm from Oracle official site:

Step 2: Installed in the base image

Step 3: I had setup following ENV variables:

ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.19/client64 ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib

This resolved my issue