# What is that command? export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

Going through this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html), I had to execute the command `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH`

It explained with

> This command inserts the path, ~/.local/bin in this example, at the
>   front of the existing PATH variable.

However, I still don't understand what exactly is happening there. What is the goal/effect of that command?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command prepend the folder `~/.local/bin` (`~` is your home folder) to your global variable $PATH (`echo $PATH` too see it).

Thanks to that, you'll be able to execute program/script stored in the folder `~/.local/bin` without typing the full path.

Example, if you have a script `myScript.sh` in your folder, before adding `~/.local/bin` to your $PATH, you can run it with the command:

```sh
~/.local/bin/myScript.sh
```

After adding `~/.local/bin` to your $PATH, you can execute it with the command:

```sh
myScript.sh
```

Comment: Now it makes sense! Great explanation. Thank you, Dorian.

Comment: What does that mean @EdMorton?

Comment: @EdMorton it’s fixed. Thanks you. Joey: it means that the shell will scan the folder ~/.local/bin before others directories in your PATH. It’s important if you have multiple command with the same name, the shell will execute the first found.