# JAVA_HOME path in Linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had open JDK installed in my Linux EC2. But then i installed oracle JDK.
As i wanted to set oracle JDK path for all  users i have set in

```
  /etc/profile
```

When i do echo $JAVA_HOME.It shows me correct path of oracle JDK.
But when i do  it shows me path of openJDK.

```
 $env
  JAVA_HOME path showing open JDK
```

Please suggest why JAVA_HOME is still pointing to openJDK and how to make it point to oracle JDK for all users.I have reboot the system but its still showing openJDK path when i do env.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the OpenJDK version of Java is on your Linux `PATH`.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix) for some ideas on how to also set your path.

Answer (score 0):

From https://superuser.com/questions/664169/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-environment-and-etc-profile

> /etc/environment - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and **path settings**

You may be seeing environment variables for a non interactive shell. Non interactive shells do not invoke `/etc/profile`.

Try setting the path in `/etc/environment` instead. This is the correct file to use for setting the system path.