# PATH issue with PyPI package, can't seem to find a solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pip, pypi

I have created a simple Python package and I have uploaded it to PyPI. I have added command scripts inside the `setup.py` file so that I can run the program at any point using my terminal. The thing is, when I install it via

```
pip3 install noty
```

typing `noty` doesnt work.
On the other hand, installing it using `sudo pip3 install noty` works just fine. I know it is a PATH issue but I can't seem to find a solution at all. Is it possible for the program to be able to run without needing to install it using sudo? Here is the github link to the package:
https://github.com/GrgBls/noty

Comment: Is there an error when running `pip3 install noty`? If you type `echo $PATH` what do you currrently see? I use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) for Python packages on macOS and Linux to avoid need of sudo and installing packages for all users, that generally helps with above.

Comment: no error at all

Comment: Try running `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` after running `pip3 install noty` and then typing `noty` to see if that works? Make sure to run `sudo pip3 uninstall noty` first to avoid duplicate installations.

Comment: I'm guessing the package has been installed in your user site when not using `sudo`, same as running `pip3 install --user noty`, see reference: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-to-the-user-site

Comment: If above works, you can fix the PATH issue permanently by following this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix/14638025#14638025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When not using `sudo` and using the Python version coming with your operating system, `pip3` might install packages to your user site because it doesn't have permissions to install packages globally for all users. This is same as if using `pip3 install --user package`.

To list binaries that have been installed in your user site under `~/.local` directory:

```
ls ~/.local/bin
```

The user site is not added into your `PATH` by default. To fix this, you can add the following to your shell init file and reload the configuration:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Put it somewhere towards the end of the file.

If you don't know how to edit the configuration, see example for modifying shell configuration when using Bash:
[How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix/14638025#14638025)

More information about the user site in Python packaging documenation:
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-to-the-user-site