# How does my system know to look in a deleted folder for a binary?

Tags: macos, unix

If I try to run `virtualenv`, I get this message:

```
$ virtualenv
-bash: /Users/me/Library/Python/3.6/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

It's not surprising that this happens, because I've removed this directories at an earlier point when trying to clean up my computer from different Python versions. However, how does my system know to look in that directory for `virtualenv`? I've looked in my bash profile, and there is no mention of `virtualenv` there.

Comment: Please Check .bashrc file

Comment: Here is a good thread of how variables are stored permanently --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type something your command interpreter has to search the command. Of course it cannot try every possible directory on your system. Then it provides to the user a way to control that process. This is the purpose of the PATH environment variable :

```
$ echo $PATH
```

will show you the actual value which looks like *dir1*:*dir2*:...:*dirn*, meaning that commands where searched for in *dir1*, then *dir2*, etc. You have to remove  the value `/Users/me/Library/Python/3.6/bin/` from it. The best way is to edit the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file to remove the *permanent* setting of this variable. Then reconnect.