# command not found: wrangler

Tags: rust, path, config, rust-cargo

I'm trying to follow these steps but get an error after step 5:

1. Run `brew install rust`
2. Run `cargo install wrangler`
3. navigate to https://dash.cloudflare.com/profile/api-tokens
4. click `create token` => `start with a template` => `edit cloudflare workers`
5. run `wrangler config`
6. put the token there
7. Download the project
8. Add the assets you want into the `public` folder
9. Run `wrangler publish`

I installed brewer, rust and wrangler successfully but I'm getting the below error when trying step 5:

`` warning: be sure to add `/Users/{my-name}/.cargo/bin` to your PATH to be able to run the installed binaries {my-name}@MacBook-Pro assets-project % wrangler config zsh: command not found: wrangler ``

Where can I find PATH to change it as the warning suggests?

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{your-name}/.cargo/bin"` in shell will do the thing. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kitzu 's answer was correct:

`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{your-name}/.cargo/bin"` in shell
worked for me.